# Unable to fetch object (which exists actually) using get_object_or_404

Tags: django

Unable to get object of a StackedInline model using get_object_or_404.
Module((this is a StackedInLine model) is linked to Course through foreign key.

```
def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
    self.module = get_object_or_404(Module, id=module_id, course__owner=request.user)
    self.model = self.get_model(model_name)
    if id:
        self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, id=id, owner=request.user)
    return super(ContentCreateUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, module_id, model_name, id)
```

**Course and Module Models below**

```
class Course(models.Model): 
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='courses_created',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    overview=models.TextField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Module(models.Model):
     course=models.ForeignKey(Course,related_name='modules',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    order=OrderField(blank=True,for_fields=['course'])#ordering of modules wrt courses


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}. {}'.format(self.order,self.title)
```

Comment: You are using ```Multi Table Inheritance``` as far as i understand. Is it True ?

Comment: I am inheriting from models.Model

Comment: First of all, your question is not clear at all. also, you are trying to hit ```DB``` from ```dispatch()``` method. ```dispatch()``` method is implemented in ```View``` class in **Django** which is base class of all **Class Based Views**. ```dispatch()``` method is responsible to call correct instance method in **Django** based on ```HTTP``` method (```get()```, ```post()``` for example). in your code ```self.get_model``` what is this ?
#
In general your are using ```get_object_or_404()``` correctly. ```course__owner``` even this span is correct. This will perform ```SQL JOIN```...

Comment: no issues from self.get_model,that is working fine.I am always getting "no modules exist for this query"..whenever I try to access template for which this dispatch() method is getting called. I have a user and he has created some modules and courses , I aim to fetch that through this but no able to do so ,don't know why!